# Azure AD B2C: The redirect URI in the request, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client

Tags: azure, blazor, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side

I am trying to [Set up sign-up and sign-in with a Google account using Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-google?pivots=b2c-user-flow). When debugging the application, I am able to register using my email. However I am unable to login using Google, I get a `The redirect URI in the request, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client` error.

**Appsettings.json:**

```
"AzureADB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://InstaTranscribe.b2clogin.com/",
    "Domain": "InstaTranscribe.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "<SomeClientId>",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpSignInUserFlow",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_PasswordResetUserFlow",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_ProfileEditingUserFlow",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

What am I missing?

```
Authorization Error
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, https://instatranscribe.b2clogin.com/instatranscribe.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/${your_client_id}?project=${your_project_number}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to paste the URL you can see in the error message to the "Authorized redirect URIs" in the Google app setup. This single one will be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you @wojtekdo, you are right, there was a typo in "Authorized redirect URIs" in the Google app setup.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps mentioned in this URL

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-google?pivots=b2c-user-flow

[image]